# Storing username with post confirmation trigger (AWS, Lambda, DynamoDB)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I try to store some parameters in a AWS DynamoDB with Cognito post confirmation trigger.
The lambda is written in node.js but I am not able to store the username of the signed up cognito user.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-central-1'});


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);

    const username = event.userName;

    await createMessage(username).then(() => {
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 201,
            body: '',
            headers: {
                'Access Control Allow Origin' : '*'
            }
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
};

function createMessage(username){
    const familyid = (new Date()).getTime().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
    const params = {
        TableName: 'eldertech',
        Item: {
            'UserId' : username,
            'message' : familyid
        }
    };
    return dynamodb.put(params).promise();
}
```

My test:

```
{
"username":"admin",
"email":"admin@admin.com",
"userId": "AD87S"
}
```

The error:
ERROR   ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key UserId in the item

Can somebody please help a newbie?

Comment: In your test there is `"userId": "AD87S"`. I don't see it used anywhere? Also is your `UserId` the actual primary key in the table with string as data type?You are using `event.userName`, but in test object there is `username`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just had a typo....

```
const username = event.username;
```

No capital n in username...